# DirectoryServicesCOMException 80072020 From IIS 7.5 Site Running Under ApplicationPoolIdentity

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, directoryservices, applicationpoolidentity

I'm having trouble hunting down an issue where an ASP.NET 4 application fails while trying to get user groups for a given user from time to time.  The application pool associated with this application is setup to run under ApplicationPoolIdentity.

Exception Info

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException
HRESULT: 80072020
Message: An operations error occurred.
Extended Message: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1
```

Stack Trace

```
    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean) 
    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() 
    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() 
    System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean) 
    System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
```

95%-99% of the time, this function works fine, but from time to time, it just starts failing.  When I change the application pool to use LocalSystem or NetworkService, it starts working.  When I change back to ApplicationPoolIdentity it begins failing again.  The only way to get the site working again with ApplicationPoolIdentity is to reboot the server.

I was able to find a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867368/applicationpoolidentity-cannot-access-network-resources/6887333), but the resolution was a reboot as well.  I'd like to find a more permanent solution short of changing the identity of the application pool.

Comment: Turns out I was just being to detailed on my search.  After I posted this question, I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686186/iis-application-using-application-pool-identity-loses-primary-token?rq=1) that appears to be the same problem with a hotfix for the solution.

Comment: I think you should post this as an answer and mark it as "Accepted" (if this site will let you). This enables future visitors to see that the problem is already resolved.

Comment: Good call, answer added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While a reboot will resolve the issue temporarily, there is a [Microsoft hotfix KB2545850](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2545850) that offers a permanent fix to the issue.

Comment: Is there a hotfix for 2012 also or might be looking at a similar problem with a different cause?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter I didn't do an exhaustive search, but there doesn't appear to be a hotfix for 2012, but most likely this was already fixed in 2012/IIS 8 based on when the hotfix was released.  This is all my guesstimate, no references to back up what I've said here.